# Remove string with sed in pattern with numbers

Tags: string, sed

I have a column like string (constant, always abc) followed by numbers ranging from 1 to 35, as follow:

```
abc1 
abc15 
abc20 
abc25 
abc30 
abc35
```

I tried to sed this to remove the abc part

```
sed -i 's/abc[0:9]/[0:9]/g' <inputfile>
```

And this is far from working .. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'abc' '{print $2}' file
awk '{sub(/abc/,"")}1' file
```

Using  `sed`

```
sed 's/abc//g' file
```

---

If you need to make sure it has correct number after `abc`

```
sed 's/abc\([1-3][05]*\)/\1/' file
```

Comment: Works fine with the sample input, but if the sample input represents merely _one_ column in a multi-column input file, things get trickier. Either way, the `g` in the sed command should be removed. `[1-3][05]*` doesn't actually match 1-35, but 1-3, 10-15, 20-25, 30-35, and also 100-155, 200-255, ...

Comment: @mklement0 I was not sure how to use `?` in `sed` regex.  I know you can do it wuth `gnu sed`  But you are wrong in the first part it does not match `10-15`, why: `[1-3]` does match `1` `2` and `3`. `[05]` matches `0` or `5`, not as you think `0` to `5`, that would be `[0-5]`

Comment: Re POSIX-compatible replacement for `\?` in basic regexes: you can use `\{0,1\}` (as an aside: similarly, `\+` can be replaced with `\{1,\}`). Thanks for catching my misinterpretation of `[05]`. However, my point was that your regex doesn't match numbers 1 _through_ 35, as requested by the OP in the opening sentence (`"numbers ranging from 1 to 35"`), although your regex does cover the _sample_ data.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the `?` help, but `sed 's/abc\([1-3][05]\{0,1\}\)/\1/'` will be true for `abc235` and return `235`.  As for the number, I did read this `ranging from 1 to 35, as follow` so that could be understand in different ways. I did take it literally. :)

Comment: Re 1 - 35: fair enough :) The issue with `sed 's/abc\([1-3][05]\{0,1\}\)/\1/' <<<'abc235'` is _not_ the use of `\{0,1\}` - which does work - but that you're not matching the _rest_ of the line, and thus do not eliminate the remaining digits through the substitution; try `sed 's/abc\([1-3][05]\{0,1\}\).*/\1/' <<<'abc205'`. (As an aside: since basic regexes do not support _alternation_ (`|`), I wouldn't even know how to truly match numbers 1 through 35 with a _basic_ regex.)